How do I find my JSON data using local storage?
I'm trying to retrieve user settings from local storage, but when I try to access the data, I get a null value, which causes an error with JSON.parse(). I suspect that the data might not be stored or has been deleted, but I'm not sure why. How can I fix this so that the code works even if the data isn’t there?
I tried to retrieve JSON data from local storage with JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userSettings')). I expected this to return an object with user settings data. However, instead of the object, I’m getting null, and JSON.parse() throws an error when trying to parse null. I expected the data to load correctly, so I’m not sure why this is happening.

"and JSON.parse() throws an error when trying to parse null" - I'm not able to replicate this assertion.  Specifically what debugging have you done and what runtime observations have you made?

JSON.parse does not throw an error when passed null.
So, you most likely have saved the data in a way that is not parseable.
Perhaps you tried to save the object directly, in which case the .toString() method was called on it, converting it to [object Object], which is not parseable.
You need to convert your data to a JSON string before storing it.
Something like
localStorage.setItem('userSettings', JSON.stringify(userSetting))


Try console.log(localStorage.getItem('userSettings')) to see what is actually stored.
Finally a couple of links on how/where to find the localStorage using the developer tools of your browser

Firefox (Local Storage / Session Storage)
Chrome (View and edit local storage)
Edge (View and edit local storage)


It seems like the localStorage value for the usersettings is not set. To check this, open your browser’s developer tools and navigate to the Application tab. On the left-hand side, you’ll find a section labeled Storage. Inside that, look for Local Storage and verify whether the relevant key is present.
During the login process, when handling authentication, you need to store data in localStorage using the following syntax.
localStorage.setItem('userSettings', JSON.stringify(userSetting)); 


I see that someone already answered you correctly, I'm adding some more precisions for you to get a better understanding:

localStorage.getItem('item') return null when it does not find the 'item' key.
JSON.parse() does not throw error on null value, but it does throw error on malformed JSON String.
localStorage.getItem(key, value) will stringify the passed value, and when running localStorage.setItem('user', { name: 'My Name' });, it automatically convert the value to: '[object Object]', which contains brackets for JSON.parse() and will cause it to throw error.

The way to handle it is to stringify object specifically to JSON string format, localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ name: 'My Name' })); and you could get it back like:
if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
  try {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    // so something, put it in state, etc.
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('JSON parse error', e);
  }
}

Use try { JSON.parse() } catch (e) {} to avoid surprise and crash. Use condition if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {} if you want to know if it's there.
And finally, while developing, you can use the Browser Console to verify that your localStorage items are there, and play with them directly in console log. An example with Google Chrome Console, under Application TAB:

